# How to restrict rows to split into next pages in python docx

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I have created a table using python-docx. I have tried AllowBreakAcrossPages, keep with next but they are not working I still see the last row in another page and the rest of the table along with headers in the previous page.

Please find the code I used

```
*#here **index** iterates through all the rows in table*


 `table.rows[**index**].AllowBreakAcrossPages = False`

*#Paragraps is content in each cell*
    paragraphs = cell.paragraphs

    for paragraph in paragraphs:

       for run in paragraph.runs:
         font = run.font
         font.size= Pt(9)
         run.space_after = Pt(0)
         run.space_before = Pt(0)
         *#the following lines are not working*
         run.keep_together = True
         run.keep_with_next = True
         run.widow_control = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are keeping the individual rows in one page, between them Word is free to split the table. [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/94eabc4c-70dc-4a8d-9297-1e70d282f59e/why-does-allowbreakacrosspages-seem-to-have-no-effect?forum=worddev) is a description of the solution in VBA, let me copy the answer in case the link goes dead sometime. (For tables having vertically merged cells there is a more complex solution which you can find following the link.)

> If you need to keep the whole table on a single page, format all the paragraphs except the last on each row with the 'keep with next' attribute. to do that, you might use code like:

```
Dim Tbl As Table, lRow As Long, Rng As Range
With Tbl
  lRow = .Rows.Count
  Set Rng = ActiveDocument.Range(.Rows(1).Range.Start, .Rows(lRow - 1).Range.End)
  .Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages = False
  .Rows.First.HeadingFormat = True
  With .Range.ParagraphFormat
    .SpaceBeforeAuto = False
    .SpaceAfterAuto = False
    .WidowControl = True
    .KeepWithNext = False
    .KeepTogether = False
    .PageBreakBefore = False
    .WordWrap = True
  End With
  With Rng.ParagraphFormat
    .KeepWithNext = True
    .KeepTogether = True
  End With
End With
Set Rng = Nothing: Set Tbl = Nothing
```

> The line ' .Rows.First.HeadingFormat = True' ensures that, if the table is too long to fit on a whole page, the heading row will appear on the subsequent pages also.